# One background image must be displayed on the whole

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background-image

I am new to iphone development.When i tried to displayed a background image for my table view ,image appears for every cells.I want display single image thats fits the screen and not displayed in every cell.Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your table view a subview of a `UIView` (let's call it `parentView`). You can then make the table view's background clear to show the `UIView` positioned underneath. You then set that `UIView` to contain an image view:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.parentView addSubview:myImageView];
```

Comment: how to make tableview a subview of UIvew

Comment: Depends. Are you designing your interface in Interface Builder? If so, drag in a `UIView` and drag the existing table view "under" the `UIView`. Otherwise, just call something like `[self.parentView addSubview:self.tableView]` if you're doing your interface programmatically.